# Text from Form as Integer in Module Function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Working with Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2013. I need to take input from a textbox on form1 and use it as an integer in functions of a module. When I call one of the functions on form1 after a click event, I get an error for invalid arguments on the public function integers. How can I get the text passed to the module and then treated as an integer?

This is what I have on form1. This worked okay on the last project, which required the calculations to be performed and displayed only on form1. This project requires calculations to be performed in a module I created, and then displayed in labels on form2. (I'm still very new to this).

```
'Define inputs as public variables
Public intNumber1 As Integer
Public intNumber2 As Integer

'Create Function to validate inputs as integers
Public Function ValidateInputFields() As Boolean
    'Try to convert each input to integer. If not, return error message, clear input, and return focus
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtNumber1.Text, intNumber1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only whole numbers.")
        txtNumber1.Clear()
        txtNumber1.Focus()
        Return False
    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtNumber2.Text, intNumber2) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only whole numbers.")
        txtNumber2.Clear()
        txtNumber2.Focus()
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Error   1   Argument not specified for parameter 'intNumber1' of 'Public               
Function AddInt() As Integer'.
```

This is the function I've written in the module:

```
'Create function to pass the values and add
    Public Function AddInt(ByVal intNumber1 As Integer, intNumber2 As  
Integer) As Integer
    'Define intSum
    Dim intSum As Integer
    'AddInt adds numbers 1 and 2
    intSum = intNumber1 + intNumber2
    'Return the result
    Return intSum
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to get a good answer, it would be a good idea to show that you have put some effort into your question.  Example: post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Jonathan I've been attempting to post my code snippets. Searching on how to get them to display properly now.

Comment: Put 4 spaces before each line of code + additional spacing as required to properly format the code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the back ticks mentioned in help to no avail.

Comment: Press enter twice after your last line of text and then either type 4 spaces or click the "Code Sample" button, or hit Ctrl+K (assuming Windows/Linux).  Back ticks are used for `inline code`, and can be used in comments, as you can see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I finally got my function calls to work correctly:

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnAdd.Click
    'create instance for results form and define sum variable
    Dim frmResults As New Results
    Dim intSum As Integer
    'If inputs are valid, display the integer sum on results form
    If ValidateInputFields() Then
        'Call Add Integer function from module
        intSum = AddInt(intNumber1, intNumber2)
        'Send answers to Results form and display
        frmResults.lblNumber1Result.Text = intNumber1.ToString()
        frmResults.lblOperatorResult.Text = "plus"
        frmResults.lblNumber2Result.Text = intNumber2.ToString()
        frmResults.lblEqualsResult.Text = intSum.ToString()
        frmResults.ShowDialog()
    End If
```

Everything worked once I added the `(intNumber1, intNumber2)` right after the function call of `AddInt`.

The `ValidateInputFields()` function is the TryParse method that @mcrimes was helping me with earlier. This did handle any non-numeric inputs or blanks left as it did in my previous project.

Thanks again @Jonathan and @mcrimes for all of your help.

Answer (score 2):

Text from a TextBox will be of type String and you need to convert it to an integer after checking whether its content can be safely interpreted as a number.

Something like this :

```
Dim num As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, num) Then
    '... it's not an integer, so don't try to use it
Else
    '... call method using "num" as your integer parameter
End If
```

Comment: I have a tryparse function on form1. It worked in the last project that I'm using the code from. Previous project did 4 simple math operations on same form, and displayed results in labels. This project calls for operations to be done in a module and results displayed in labels on a second form (form2). @mcrimes

Comment: It sounds then like they're wanting you to create a new module (for which I'm assuming you have some basic course materials with guidance) which takes a String as the input (so you can pass the TextBox's Text property directly to) and then do the Integer.TryParse there before using it.  Same concept, different organisation of code.  Good coding comes from experimentation and trial & error while you're learning.  Give it a shot and see what works.

Comment: Yes, I had to create a new module. I'll play around with declaring the strings and then converting to integers in the module to see if I can get that to work. Thank you.